# How can I use Automator to open a website & log in everyday at a certain time?

Tags: safari, applescript, automator, ical

I need to set up an auto log in for an Intranet web site so I can get right to work with no delays. I want Automator to open safari, go to the page, input log in and password credentials and hit log in (enter) on a daily basis (9am daily) I'd like to use Automator or AppleScript if at all possible. I've heard that lastpass or 1password may have this functionality and I have both paid versions and cannot find any way to use them either.

I have read a lot of questions posted on this topic previously and have not found a solution nor has Google been my friend this time around. :)

Comment: Have you tried applescript and used the 'record' function?

Comment: That's pretty much default behaviour since Lion - When i launch Safari I'm right where i left off last session. I can't imagine any other behaviour these days; would drive me mad having to manually open new tabs for the 15 or 20 places I want to be right there at launch.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin, I did try it and had no luck with it. I need an automated process that works with out me in front of it.

Comment: I keep trying the record but it misses steps and is not editable. Am I doing something wrong or is it unruly like that?

Comment: Follow-up questions should be asked as a separate question. However, site recommendation for learning resources are off-topic. You might want to try [chat].

Answer (score -1):

if you can use firefox instead of safari you can use:

set firefox with iMacros
set a cronjob with croonix that launch firefox